# Postgres unexpected result from product with two categories

Tags: postgresql

I've created 3 tables: item, item_category and category, when I select items with two specific categories it returns 0 rows, even when I have items with those categories...

Does anyone have any idea why is that happening?

For example the select without filters I'm using is:

```
SELECT i.item_id, c.cate_friendly_id
FROM item i , item_category ic, category c
WHERE
i.item_id = ic.item_id 
AND ic.cate_id = c.cate_id
```

Which returns the rows

```
1;"aaaa"
1;"7777"
1;"bbbb"
2;"aaaa"
2;"1111"
2;"cccc"
```

It is what I was expecting also returns the right rows when I select items with cate_friendly_id = "7777" for example:

```
SELECT i.item_id, c.cate_friendly_id
FROM item i , item_category ic, category c
WHERE
i.item_id = ic.item_id 
AND ic.cate_id = c.cate_id 
AND ( 
    c.cate_friendly_id = '7777' 
)
```

Return 1 row which is:

```
1;"7777"
```

And return 2 rows if I filter by category "aaaa"

```
1;"aaaa"
2;"aaaa"
```

That is also fine, but when I select items both with cate_friendly_id = "aaaa" and "7777", no row is found, for example:

```
SELECT i.item_id, c.cate_friendly_id
FROM item i , item_category ic, category c
WHERE
i.item_id = ic.item_id 
AND ic.cate_id = c.cate_id 
AND ( 
    c.cate_friendly_id = 'aaaa' 
    AND c.cate_friendly_id = '7777' 
)
```

Was it not supposed to return me item 1 witch has both category "aaaa" and "7777"?

Thanks you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected answer, as any single category row is either `'aaaa'` or `'7777'` but not both.

What you want is to query the items having two rows, one for `'aaaa'` and one for `'7777'`, like

```
SELECT i.item_id
FROM item i , item_category ic, category c
WHERE
  i.item_id = ic.item_id 
  AND ic.cate_id = c.cate_id 
  AND c.cate_friendly_id in ( 'aaaa', '7777')
GROUP BY i.item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```